# How To Get Salesforce Table Names using SOQL

Tags: salesforce, soql

How can I view all the available tables in my Salesforce instance using SOQL? Is it possible to view additional parameters, such as whether the table is queryable, or whether it is customizable?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066774/querying-salesforce-object-column-names-w-soql?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`EntityDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) is a decent start (experiment with the WHERE clause, there are way more tables even in vanilla SF than you think)

```
SELECT KeyPrefix, QualifiedApiName, Label, IsQueryable, IsDeprecatedAndHidden, IsCustomSetting
FROM EntityDefinition
WHERE IsCustomizable = true AND IsCustomSetting = false
```

Comment: Hi again
Is there any query or something where we can get or view the fields of the table of salesforce?

Comment: Yep, `FieldDefinition`. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067076/313628